# Google Birthday Calendar Wrong Year

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-calendar-api, google-people-api

I am having issue when i am getting google birthday calendar. I am getting wrong year in google birthday calendar.

Ex:
In my google contacts i am having contact name - Deepak whose birthday - 19/04/1990. So this contact birthday showing in the google birthday calendar. When i am fetching google birthday calendar i am getting date like 2017-04-19, 2018-04-19, 2019-04-19. How can i get contact exact birthday with year from google birthday calendar?

Response From Google Calendar API

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [kind] => calendar#event
        [etag] => "3060534890000000"
        [id] => 2017_BIRTHDAY_4a7a6b868dd53910
        [status] => confirmed
        [htmlLink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxN19CSVJUSERBWV80YTdhNmI4NjhkZDUzOTEwICNjb250YWN0c0B2
        [created] => 2018-06-29T10:17:25.000Z
        [updated] => 2018-06-29T10:17:25.000Z
        [summary] => Deepak's birthday
        [description] => This is Deepak's birthday!
        [creator] => Array
            (
                [email] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
                [displayName] => Contacts
                [self] => 1
            )

        [organizer] => Array
            (
                [email] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
                [displayName] => Contacts
                [self] => 1
            )

        [start] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2017-06-30
            )

        [end] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2017-07-01
            )

        [visibility] => public
        [iCalUID] => 2017_BIRTHDAY_4a7a6b868dd53910@google.com
        [sequence] => 0
        [gadget] => Array
            (
                [iconLink] => https://calendar.google.com/googlecalendar/images/cake.gif
                [preferences] => Array
                    (
                        [goo.contactsGivenName] => Deepak
                        [goo.contactsEventType] => BIRTHDAY
                        [goo.contactsFullName] => Deepak
                        [goo.isGPlusUser] => false
                        [goo.contactsContactId] => 4a7a6b868dd53910
                        [goo.contactsIsMyContact] => true
                    )

            )

        [reminders] => Array
            (
                [useDefault] => 1
            )

    )


[1] => Array
    (
        [kind] => calendar#event
        [etag] => "3060534890000000"
        [id] => 2018_BIRTHDAY_4a7a6b868dd53910
        [status] => confirmed
        [htmlLink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxOF9CSVJUSERBWV80YTdhNmI4NjhkZDUzOTEwICNjb250YWN0c0B2
        [created] => 2018-06-29T10:17:25.000Z
        [updated] => 2018-06-29T10:17:25.000Z
        [summary] => Deepak's birthday
        [description] => This is Deepak's birthday!
        [creator] => Array
            (
                [email] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
                [displayName] => Contacts
                [self] => 1
            )

        [organizer] => Array
            (
                [email] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
                [displayName] => Contacts
                [self] => 1
            )

        [start] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2018-06-30
            )

        [end] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2018-07-01
            )

        [visibility] => public
        [iCalUID] => 2018_BIRTHDAY_4a7a6b868dd53910@google.com
        [sequence] => 0
        [gadget] => Array
            (
                [iconLink] => https://calendar.google.com/googlecalendar/images/cake.gif
                [preferences] => Array
                    (
                        [goo.contactsGivenName] => Deepak
                        [goo.contactsEventType] => BIRTHDAY
                        [goo.contactsFullName] => Deepak
                        [goo.isGPlusUser] => false
                        [goo.contactsContactId] => 4a7a6b868dd53910
                        [goo.contactsIsMyContact] => true
                    )

            )

        [reminders] => Array
            (
                [useDefault] => 1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
(
    [kind] => calendar#event
    [etag] => "3060534890000000"
    [id] => 2019_BIRTHDAY_4a7a6b868dd53910
    [status] => confirmed
    [htmlLink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxOV9CSVJUSERBWV80YTdhNmI4NjhkZDUzOTEwICNjb250YWN0c0B2
    [created] => 2018-06-29T10:17:25.000Z
    [updated] => 2018-06-29T10:17:25.000Z
    [summary] => Deepak's birthday
    [description] => This is Deepak's birthday!
    [creator] => Array
        (
            [email] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
            [displayName] => Contacts
            [self] => 1
        )

    [organizer] => Array
        (
            [email] => #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
            [displayName] => Contacts
            [self] => 1
        )

    [start] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-06-30
        )

    [end] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-07-01
        )

    [visibility] => public
    [iCalUID] => 2019_BIRTHDAY_4a7a6b868dd53910@google.com
    [sequence] => 0
    [gadget] => Array
        (
            [iconLink] => https://calendar.google.com/googlecalendar/images/cake.gif
            [preferences] => Array
                (
                    [goo.contactsGivenName] => Deepak
                    [goo.contactsEventType] => BIRTHDAY
                    [goo.contactsFullName] => Deepak
                    [goo.isGPlusUser] => false
                    [goo.contactsContactId] => 4a7a6b868dd53910
                    [goo.contactsIsMyContact] => true
                )

        )

    [reminders] => Array
        (
            [useDefault] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: the calendar doesn't contain the original date of birth, it contains reminders for each annual birthday. There's nothing "wrong" with the data, you're simply looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Google calendar and google contacts are two different things. There is also a difference between a date of birth and a birthday.  The former occurs only once the latter occurs once a year.

> Ex: In my google contacts I am having contact name - Deepak whose birthday - 19/04/1990.

This is your entry in your address book for this user. Its the users date of birth.

> So this contact birthday showing in the google birthday calendar. When i am fetching google birthday calendar i am getting date like 2017-04-19, 2018-04-19, 2019-04-19.

Google calendar birthday calendar gives you an event for each year for the users birthday that year.  So that you dont forget to send flowers.

> How can i get contact exact birthday with year from google birthday calendar?

You should be going though the [google contacts api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) directly if you just want the data from your google contacts.